# Rails замена кавычек на елочки

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Пишу на рельсах, необходимо в html заменить кавычки "" на елочки «»

```
запись в базе данных :
"ЗАО \"Компания\""
```

запись на вьюхе:
ЗАО "Компания"
устанавливал гем gilenson:

```
<%= "#{@owner.name.gilensize}" %>
```

получил прямой вывод

```
ЗАО&#160;&#171;<span class="nobr">Компания</span>&#187;
```

именно такую запись, как-будто использован метод .inspect
. подскажите, как правильно решить: найти билиотеку, использовать javascript, либо что-то иное? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<%= @owner.name.gilensize.html_safe %>
Добавление метода html_safe решает проблемы вывода в html